# JOIN VIEWs containing UNION ALL: performance disaster?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, join, union-all

Consider the following standard table/subtable relationship in a MS SQL Server DB:

```
PARENT
-ID (PK)
-OTHER_FIELD

CHILD
-ID (PK)
-PARENT_ID (FK)
-OTHER_FIELD
```

Now also consider that there exist other versions of these tables in the DB (with the same structure): PARENT_2/CHILD_2, PARENT_3/CHILD_3, PARENT_4/CHILD_4.

I want to create a standard mechanism to select data from all of the tables combined in a simple query. The first thing that came to mind is:

```
PARENT_VIEW = PARENT UNION ALL PARENT_2 UNION ALL PARENT_3 UNION ALL PARENT_4
CHILD_VIEW = CHILD UNION ALL CHILD_2 UNION ALL CHILD_3 UNION ALL CHILD_4
```

But I'm concerned that queries containing JOINs against these views will be horrendous due to each row in the PARENT_VIEW having to scan each row in the CHILD_VIEW for each JOIN. There are actually multiple different CHILD tables (resulting in multiple JOINs) and I'll be dealing with large amounts of data in due course. I don't think this will scale.

Ideally I want to preserve the structure of the tables (opposed to flattening them out).

Queries made against the combined tables would always be filtered using WHERE conditions.

I'm aware of the alternative approach of writing my queries for each PARENT/CHILD table separately and using UNION ALL on each result set so the JOIN would be much more efficient.

I also considered a conditional join, but have not yet explored this further.

Any suggestions how to proceed (ideally with some DBMS science to back it up)?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is not an anti-pattern in all cases. SQL Server understands unions and can transform them is many ways. It is probably only possible to say whether a given plan is good enough or not.

Comment: Are you just concerned or do you experience actual issues? Have you measured? It would not be too hard to fill in a couple of 100,000 (or million, whatever you expect) rows of dummy data and measure performance.

Comment: This is a WIP, so no _actual_ issues to date. I'm currently filling up a DB and analysing execution plans to observe if performance is good _enough_. What I'm hoping for (still) is a for an experienced DBA to weigh in with "this is terrible, because... Consider this other approach..." or "actually your concerns are invalid, because...".

Comment: As a DB design, it's not terrible, unless it performs badly. Even then it could be down to things not related to the DB design - large volumes of data on memory poor machine, slow discs on poorly designed network drives etc. The only thing I would be worried about, sans evidence of poor perf, would be duplicate PK's in Parent tables and in the Child tables.

Comment: Great, thanks for the input. I'll proceed on the basis that this is not an anti-pattern / design disaster and look at performance alone.